# How to install Certbot on Ubuntu - GCP machine

Tags: ubuntu, apt, certbot

I'm following  [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/cd90d1ed3c462fe3bddd11bf8953a896) and I am using google cloud instance .

When I try to install the certbot and I run the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot`

I getting the following error:

```
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp_4tz_t5w/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmp_4tz_t5w/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 8C47BE8E75BCA694: public key "Launchpad PPA for certbot" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

edit: I success to do it https with open-ssl. 
rely on this tutorials [first](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/)  [second](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have trouble installing certbot. Which operating system are you using?

On newer versions of Ubuntu you have to install the universe repos and software-properties before a PPA can be added. Maybe this helps:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update
```

Further information about installing certbot [here](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/install.html)

Comment: Step 3: " The PPA has been DEPRECATED.

To get up to date instructions on how to get certbot for your systems, please see https://certbot.eff.org/docs/install.html.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~certbot/+archive/ubuntu/certbot
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it"